# Neo4J: Pods logs Neo4j Invalid Username

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, kubernetes-statefulset

Has anyone deployed a Neo4J graph DB or any stateful application to Kubernetes using Helm Charts? I have this task that requires me to deploy a Neo4J graph DB to Kubernetes.

**Issue**: The Pod keeps on crashing as it cannot get the username provided, and throws the following logs even when the username is provided:
*Invalid username, it must be neo4j* when you run **kubectl logs neo4j-chart-0**  command. What am I doing wrong?

```
command:
      - "/bin/bash"
      - "-c"
      - |
        export NEO4J_dbms_connectors_default__advertised__address=$(hostname -f)
        export NEO4J_causal__clustering_discovery__advertised__address=$(hostname -f):5000
        export NEO4J_causal__clustering_transaction__advertised__address=$(hostname -f):6000
        export NEO4J_causal__clustering_raft__advertised__address=$(hostname -f):7000

        if [ "${AUTH_ENABLED:-}" == "true" ]; then
          export NEO4J_AUTH=“neo4j/${NEO4J_SECRETS_PASSWORD}”
        else
          export NEO4J_AUTH=“none”
        fi

        exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "neo4j"
```

Comment: what is the helm command that you executed?

Answer (score 1):

I found out I had mismatched quotes:

`“neo4j/${NEO4J_SECRETS_PASSWORD}”`

Which is different from this `"neo4j/${NEO4J_SECRETS_PASSWORD"`.

Comment: @rabello Yes. This worked for me. It was just a typo when providing Neo4J username and password.